# Implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' on MinGW

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, winsock2, getaddrinfo

I have a C program that uses `getaddrinfo()`. It works as expected on Linux and Mac OS X.

I'm in the middle of porting it to Windows.

When I compile it (with MinGW gcc) I get the following warnings:

```
ext/socket/socket.c: In function 'sl_tcp_socket_init':
ext/socket/socket.c:98:5: warning implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ext/socket/socket.c:104:9: warning implicit declaration of function 'freeaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Then the entire thing fails to link with undefined references to `getaddrinfo()` and `freeaddrinfo()`.

Now, according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `getaddrinfo()` is supported on Windows and is located in the header file `Ws2tcpip.h` and the library file `Ws2_32.lib`.

I'm including `Ws2tcpip.h` and linking with `-lWs2_32`, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a look at line 297 of ws2tcpip.h, you can see that there's a check of the value of _WIN32_WINNT.

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo (struct addrinfo*);
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
                struct addrinfo**);
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr*,socklen_t,char*,DWORD,
               char*,DWORD,int);
#else
/* FIXME: Need WS protocol-independent API helpers.  */
#endif
```

Just #define `_WIN32_WINNT` before your includes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code compiler-wide you should actually also define `NTDDI_VERSION` with the same OS version as `_WIN32_WINNT`. Without that defining only `_WIN32_WINNT` will not let you to use `getaddrinfo()` with some compilers (i.e. Watcom). It is better to wrap it in the same way as Windows SDK does:

```
#define _NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)    ver##0000
#define _NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(ver)     _NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#  define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#endif
#ifndef NTDDI_VERSION
#  define NTDDI_VERSION _NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(_WIN32_WINNT)
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposedly the proper way to fix this is:

```
#define WINVER WindowsXP
```

Or perhaps more sensibly adding `-DWINVER=WindowsXP` to your `CPPFLAGS`.

Ref: http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/Undefined-reference-to-getaddrinfo-td5694.html

Note: didn’t work for me however.