# Cross-platform sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I know, Windows doesn't use UNIX sockets while Mac OS does. Until this point my software was cross-platform without any code changes. But now I want it to do some network communication. I know about POSIX sockets, but I know nothing about Windows' ones. The goal is to implement a simple cross-platform socket server.

Could you please explain to me the differences between POSIX and Winsock sockets and how I may go about writing cross platform networking code?

Comment: It goes beyond pure sockets, but I find 0mq (ZeroMq) very interesting.

Comment: What I usually do, is take the POSIX program and compile using gcc under Cygwin, then distribute like that ;-) Additional bonus: it makes my life on Windows a lot easier.

Comment: Unfortunately(?) questions asking recommendations are [explicitly off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. However, one solution is to use either Cygwin (if you need other Unix-like infrastructure) or Mingw (if you don't need a "fake unix" environment for your program, just the C libraries/APIs are enough) to directly build your Unix/Linux source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952733/using-sys-socket-h-functions-on-windows

Comment: Reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it appears that simple client/server applications should be easily portable, i.e. one may get away with a few defines to cater to the differences but essentially keep a common source. EDIT: I See that @Mat linked to a question which had a similar accepted answer.

Comment: This is the kind of question that was highly useful, sorry it got closed

Comment: Agree, this question has been viewed 46 thousand times.   Closing everything as off topic or out of bounds, even when they are useful questions is making StackOverflow far less useful than it could be. 

Why is there such a rigid adherence to the rules, and not people making sensible decisions as to whether a question is valuable?  Boo.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

### WinSock versus POSIX Sockets

[WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) sockets work in a similar manner - mainly because [Windows sockets were originally based on code from BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution):

> Although these proprietary BSD derivatives were largely superseded by the UNIX System V Release 4 and OSF/1 systems in the 1990s (both of which incorporated BSD code and are the basis of other modern Unix systems), later BSD releases provided a basis for several open source development projects, e.g. FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Darwin or PC-BSD, that are ongoing. These, in turn, have been incorporated in whole or in part in modern proprietary operating systems, e.g. **the TCP/IP (IPv4 only) networking code in Microsoft Windows** and most of the foundation of Apple's OS X and iOS.

However, there are a few things you'll need to handle differently if you want to write "socket-library-agnostic" code.

*Note: The following examples have been tested using Code::Blocks and GCC on Windows XP (x86) and Debian Testing (AMD64).*

#### The header and lib files are different

You'll need to include different header files depending on whether you're using Windows or not:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  /* See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765743/getaddrinfo-on-win32 */
  #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501  /* Windows XP. */
  #endif
  #include <winsock2.h>
  #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#else
  /* Assume that any non-Windows platform uses POSIX-style sockets instead. */
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netdb.h>  /* Needed for getaddrinfo() and freeaddrinfo() */
  #include <unistd.h> /* Needed for close() */
#endif
```

You'll also need to link with `Ws2_32` lib file on Windows.

#### WinSock requires initialisation and cleanup.

The functions below illustrate how you can initialise WinSock v1.1 and clean up afterwards:

```
int sockInit(void)
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsa_data);
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}

int sockQuit(void)
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    return WSACleanup();
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}
```

#### Socket handles are UNSIGNED on Winsock

For POSIX-style sockets, you can simply use `int` to store a socket handle. Invalid sockets are indicated by a negative value.

However, [WinSock sockets are UNSIGNED integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with a special constant (`INVALID_SOCKET`) used instead of negative numbers.

You can abstract the differences by `typedef`ing SOCKET as `int` on POSIX and hiding the "valid socket" check behind a macro or function.

#### Sockets are closed differently

The function below illustrates the differences:

```
/* Note: For POSIX, typedef SOCKET as an int. */

int sockClose(SOCKET sock)
{

  int status = 0;

  #ifdef _WIN32
    status = shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    if (status == 0) { status = closesocket(sock); }
  #else
    status = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) { status = close(sock); }
  #endif

  return status;

}
```

#### In general though, they're pretty similar.

If you stick to "common" functions (such as `send()` or `recv()`) and avoid platform-specific stuff (such as [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) then you should be fine.

Comment: One other difference is that Windows' `WinSock` doesn't work well with basic `read()` and `write()` calls that POSIX sockets work with just fine.  For example, calling `write( socket, buffer, bytes )` on a WinSock can fail while `send( socket, buffer, bytes, 0 )` on the exact same socket works fine.

Comment: Why are you telling the OP to link against Winsock 2 and telling they how to clean up Winsock 1 sockets?

Comment: @rstackhouse you clean it up by upgrading to

Comment: using this, I receive error: `error C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings`. So, perhaps this answer should be updated?

Answer (score 6):

I can also suggest the [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys) library: works on both Windows and UNIX systems (see the full list on the project page) with various compilers. Supports IPv4 and IPv6. It has the tests where you can see the usage examples. The library itself is lightweight and portable.

Answer (score 4):

There are many libraries and toolkits that support cross platform sockets, depending on what you are doing, you can use (to name a few):

- openssl
- apache portable runtime
- libtcl

If you don't want to have a dependency on an external library, all of the above packages have fairly permissive licenses, so you can use their code as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The regular sockets (those in AF_INET address family) which you need to build a socket server are equally supported on all platforms.

Do not confuse them with Unix sockets (those in AF_UNIX address family) - such sockets are highly specific for a Unix world, and are used for a highly specific goals. You wouldn't ever need them for a simple socket server application.