# Install libpcap

Tags: c++, cmake, pcap, libpcap

Can someone explain me how to install libpcap?  I downloaded libpcap-1.9.1 from official site (tcpdump). There are a lot of files and i cant understand what to do. i tried:

```
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(libpcap-1.9.1)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libpcap-1.9.1/cmake/Modules")
find_package(Packet REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PACKET_LIBRARY})
```

But it doesnt work

Comment: Did you read through [the Documentation](https://www.tcpdump.org/index.html#documentation)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i didnt find solution to my problem in documentation

Comment: which platform are you using? windows? linux?

Comment: @Waqar windows platform

Comment: have you tried just using `target_link_libraries()` with `add_subdirectory()`?

Comment: Posting a [mcve] is always a good idea.

Comment: @Waqar i post code from my `CMakeLists.txt` from project. thats all what i have tried to do. in `.cpp` i include `pcap.h` but when i try to use some methods from pcap it says "undefined reference to ...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `add_subdirectory()` with `target_link_libraries()`:

```
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(libpcap-1.9.1)

add_subdirectory(libpcap-1.9.1)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE pcap)
```

Comment: i tried this and it give me another error "CMake Error at libpcap-1.9.1/CMakeLists.txt:412 (message): getaddrinfo is required, but wasn't found" but i think the problem is in the library itself.

Comment: are you using `mingw`?

Comment: I suspect it's because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765743/implicit-declaration-of-function-getaddrinfo-on-mingw

Comment: can you try adding the definition using: `target_compile_definitions(pcap PUBLIC _WIN32_WINNT=0x501)` before linking. It may solve the issue

Comment: or `add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)`,

Comment: It is already specified here: https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/f87b39e9b6fed60e28c7df050a5dfeb2f6f22abb/CMakeLists.txt#L152 so I am not sure what the actual problem might be.