# recv() return -1 on peer disconnect for non blocking tcp ip socket

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I am using tcp/ip socket and i have read about `recv` function . So whenever a peer is disconnected recv return 0 as per documentation but on windows it is not returnig zero instead it return -1 and the value in `errono` is `0` I am unable to understand why it is doing so. The same code is working perfect in linux.

```cpp
// some headers i used
#ifdef _WIN32
/* See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765743/getaddrinfo-on-win32 */
#    ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#        define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 /* Windows XP. */
#    endif
#    include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#    include <winsock2.h>

#    ifdef _MSC_VER
#        pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#    endif

#    define SHUT_RDWR SD_BOTH
#else
/* Assume that any non-Windows platform uses POSIX-style sockets instead. */
#    include <arpa/inet.h>
#    include <fcntl.h>
#    include <netinet/in.h>
#    include <netinet/tcp.h>
#    include <sys/socket.h>
#    include <unistd.h>

#    define NO_ERROR 0
#    define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#    define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#endif

// MSG_DONTWAIT is not available on some platforms, if it doesn't exist define it as 0
#if !defined(MSG_DONTWAIT)
#    define MSG_DONTWAIT 0
#endif
//

std::vector<std::string> Peer::read(const int length)
{
    static std::vector<char> tempRecvBuf(2 * 1000000);
    tempRecvBuf.clear();
    int recv = ::recv(m_socket.resource(), &tempRecvBuf[0], length, MSG_DONTWAIT);

    if (recv == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
        if (errno == WSAECONNRESET) {
            return {};
        }
        else {
            return {};
    }

    if (recv == 0) {
        // Connection is no longer valid, remote has been disconnected
        m_connected = false;
        this->m_master->events()->onPeerDisconnect()->trigger(this);
        this->m_master->peers()->remove(this);
        return {};
    }
```

Comment: "on windows it is not returnig zero instead it return -1 and the value in errono is 0": on Windows the value of `errno` is irrelevant. You should be looking at the value of `WSAGetLastError()`. What was it?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page of the Microsoft Windows Sockets documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv), the function `recv` will return `0` on [graceful shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2) and `SOCKET_ERROR` (which is probably defined as `-1`) on an error (including an abortive shutdown). As stated in the documentation, you must call [`WSAGetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) to obtain the error code. It is not stored in `errno`.

This behavior differs from the [POSIX version of the function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recv.3p.html), which does set `errno` when an error occurs.

Comment: `::recv()` is returning -1 on peer disconnect instead it should return 0. I have tried it but a sample code will be very help full.

Comment: As stated in my answer, the `recv` function will only return `0` on a **graceful** shutdown. On an **abortive** shutdown ("connection reset by peer"), it will return `SOCKET_ERROR` (which is probably defined as `-1`) and `WSAGetLastError` will return `WSAECONNRESET`. Did you try calling `WSAGetLastError` after `recv` returned `-1`?

Comment: @UmarFarooq: After obtaining the error code from `WSAGetLastError`, you can look it up in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2).

Comment: i have edited the question can you please check as the problem is still not solved

Comment: @UmarFarooq: Why are you still using `errno`? I told you that you must use [`WSAGetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) instead. I suggest that you write `if (recv == SOCKET_ERROR ) std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;` and look up the error code in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2). If the error code is `WSAECONNRESET`, then you know that the connection was closed due to an abortive shutdown, i.e. that there was not graceful shutdown.

Comment: @UmarFarooq: Of course, `std::cout` will only work if you are running a console application. If you are running a graphical application, you will have to use `MessageBox` or `OutputDebugString` instead.